# Way to make a sailing frigate dangerous in a semi-modern world

Tags: science-based, ships, naval-combat

I need to find a way to make an age of sail type naval frigate comparable to those of rougly the 1770's (admittedly with some ''ahead of it's time'' design changes) a threat to a naval ship comparable to the ironclads of the late 1860's early 1870's (like those french ''tumblehome'' ships or something like H.M.S. Devastation of 1871)
I would love to preferably do this by changing the ammunition fired from it's guns rather than fundamentally changing the ship itself (no adding screws or steam propulsion).
Any idea how i could go about doing this in a way that is even the slightest bit believable?

Edit: if it is of any help, the ways this frigate was ''ahead of its time'' when it was put into service (in this world's equivalent of the early 1770's) was:

1. had a copper plated keel when most ships did not.
2. had rifled breech loading guns (comparable to RBL 7-inch Armstrong guns) when the all others still had smooth bore muzzle-loaders
3. Guns are mounted on carriages that through use of a spring mechanism realign themselves after firing so the gun crew does not have to roll the guns back into place manually
4. carried guns with a caliber that outclassed ships of the line (110 pounders when its opponents at most had 36 pounders)
5. has a way sharper bow and keel shape (more akin to a cross between the steam assisted sail frigates of the 1860's and a tea clipper) than it's contemporaries.
6. was larger and thus carried more sail than its contemporaries (size comparable to USS Constitution)
7. Decks below the waterline are compartmentalised in case of flooding

This however was when this ship was new, and what i am looking for is a way to make this ship a threat to a ship (as described above) roughly 70 to 100 years more modern (late 18th century vs mid to late 19th century) opponent while preferrably only changing the munitions it is firing.

NOTE: we are talking a 1 on 1 naval battle/skirmish not a full on fleet vs fleet confrontation.

Comment: The 18th century frigate cannot hit anything beyond a few hundred yards except by blind luck. The late 19th century naval ships had fire directors who computed accurate firing solutions (by hand, using optical rangefinders and tables) and their guns could be aimed with sub-degree accuracy, so that they would have been capable to engage the frigate from waaaaay beyond its effective cannon range.

Comment: (In other words, following on from @AlexP's comment, changing the munitions does exactly nothing when your opponent can pound you into splinters from five times your engagement envelope.  )

Comment: If that changes anything, the guns mounted by the frigate (a fictional gun just based/inspired by above mentioned Armstrong guns) have (in this fictional setting) an effective firing range of 3500 meters (about 3700 yards if my math holds up)

Comment: You can upgrade the weapons but a ship made out of wood provides as much defence as a piece of paper to modern weapons. Also sails don't cut it compared to modern faster vessels.

Comment: ''modern'' in the sense of this question being 19th century (victorian)

Comment: Weren't the cannons used to attack meter thick stone walls. I mean there was a reason they started using iron so yeah your ship is still very vulnerable. Though it being reliant on sails is probably the worst thing.

Comment: Look @Blue Devil without mayor structural changes it is impossible to make a sailing ship be able to compete with an iron clad steam ship. It is like asking how could a medieval knight take down a tank. Sure you can give it enough weapons make it a threat like torpedoes would be a good idea. But you won't be able to make it compete with a more modern warship in a 1 vs 1.

Comment: So even if the sailing ship has guns of comparable (or larger) caliber and (if the wind is favorable) a higher top speed than the steamship it still would not have a chance unless i also give it steam propulsion as well?

Comment: I don't really know the max speed of the ship types but a steam ship could probably just flee from a sail ship if it wants to or if it's fast enough just run circles around the sailship. I would also suggest reinforcing the structure of the ship with iron plates beams though i don't know if this would make it sink. But then still you need a few lucky hits to be able to defeat a more modern ship.

Comment: Well concerning speed i have done some research and the fastest i could believably make this sailing frigate go would be around 22 knots while an ironclad like HMS Devastation topped out at 14 knots. And perhaps to add armor i could go the HMS Warrior route and have steel plates between the wood of the inner and outer parts of the hull. And concerning armament i think as long as the frigate would be lucky enough to evade the ironclads main turrets it would have an offensive chance seeing how its would have more guns (64) than the ironclad but of a caliber able to penetrate the steam vessel

Comment: @Blue Devil Would probably make the ship a lot more durable. Equip it with better weapons and i think you are good to go. Though while you are probably still in a disadvantage i think your ship might stand a chance.

Comment: Standing a chance is good enough, the circumstances this fight has to take place in have in universe to show that experience and planning can trump more modern tech.

Comment: Read up on the [Battle of Lissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Lissa_(1866)) in 1866. It has a lot of material for you.

Comment: *"I could believably make this sailing frigate go around 22 knots":* Yes, but only in *one* specific direction. Guess what: the modern ship won't be there, it will be one mile upwind of the frigate, and the sailing frigate won't be able to do anything about it. Steam-powered ships don't care about having the [weather gage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_gage).

Comment: To add - the changes in gunnery, precision machining, optics etc. Mean this is highly unlikely. It's like asking can a single shot smoothbore musket compete with a modern Semi-Auto sporting rifle.

Comment: define threat, just need to be dangerous in a single one off specialized situation, sure that possible, an general threat on open seas no way in heaven or earth.

Answer (score 3):

### You need to improve your cannons, not your shells.

The RBL 7-inch Armstrong gun had an issue with the sealing mechanism which limited how much gun powder you could safely charge it with.  If you put in more than 11-12 lb of powder, you risked blowing open the back of the cannon; so, even though it had a large enough projectile to do a lot of damage in theory, it could only achieve a muzzle velocity of about 1100 fps and had a max range of about 3.2km.

The innovation that your ship needs is the elswick cup which is a mechanism for sealing a breech loaded cannon using the force of the gun's own recoil.  So, instead of being limited to how tightly a human can turn a screw, the gun is only limited by the strength of the steel that it is made out of.  Because of this, later era breech loading cannons like the BL 6-inch gun Mk V could pack enough charge to fire a shell at about 1,900 fps and had a max range of just over 7.3km. Even though this was only a 6" 100lb gun, the higher velocity means that it had about 2.5 times has much striking power as the RBL 7-inch Armstrong which was enough to penetrate most Ironclads: something your older cannons could not do.

But more important than the stopping power is the added range.  An ironclad's cannons will reliable sink a wooden ship very quickly, and it's steam engines mean it is generally more maneuverable.  So, if you can't out tank it and you can't our manuvore it, your only remaining hope of survival is to out reach it.  Those extra 4km of range are all the "armor" your ship needs.  If it can sink the ironclad before it can close that gap, then you win, if the ironclad can avoid enough shots to close the gap, then it will win.

Even if you could get the older style of cannon to pack a shape charged or other more modern penetrator, the cannon will still be range limited. Just having enough firepower to penetrate an ironclad will not be big enough of an advantage to overcome the greater mobility of a steam powered ship.

Historically, the elswick cup was first implemented in 1884, only a few years after your proposed time period; so, if in your story the wooden warship was used as a testing platform for a this new prototype cannon, the timeframes would match up well enough to be perfectly believable.

Comment: The projectiles may fly up to 7.3 km, all right. The problem is that they could not *hit* anything at more than a very few hundred meters, except by chance, because they could not *aim* the guns except by turning the entire ship, and they could not *time* the fire to account for the roll of their ship and for the relative movement of the ship and the target. The modern ship computes firing solutions which lay the guns and time the fire with great precision.

Comment: @AlexP the ship is old, but not out of its time period.  The older ship would be able to do those things just as well as newer ships, because those are features of the crew and cannons, not of the ship itself.  A good parallel would be the F-15.  Even though it does not have the stealth features of a newer fighter like the F-22 or F-35, there are still plenty in service that have been refitted with modern electronics and weapon systems making them still a very capable aircraft in modern conflicts.

Comment: They are not features of the cannon, they are features of the weapons platform. How do you mount and operate rotating gun mounts on a sailing ship?

Comment: @Nosajimiki - capable in their own right? Sure. Capable against a newer fighter? No. This is much the same problem as this question. The improvements in gunnery and precision machining means that before the frigate has spotted the enemy, they've been targeted and engaged.

Comment: @AlexP Many pre turret era cannons featured simi-circular rails that could be used to rotate the cannon for aiming.  You did not get a full 360 degree motion like you would with a top mounted turret, but it was enough that a broadside cannon had about 30 degrees of articulation which is enough to range a shot.

Comment: @TheDemonLord A modernized F-15 can still outperform most active service fighters in the world, and like the ships thing, its a range issue.  Because they have been modernized with 5th generation radar, targeting, and missile systems, they are much more comparable with 5th generation fighters than other 4th generation fighters.   It's the whole reason Ukraine wants F-15.  Although they are not stealth, they have been upgraded to have the reach to be able to go toe to toe with Russia's 5th gen fighters.

Comment: As for the frigate thing, the hull does not define the weapon system.  In fact, in the Victorian era, there were many wooden warships still in service that had been upgraded to us those newer, better designed cannons and ranging technology, and there were naval conflicts where wooden ships sunk ironclads using the newer cannons.  Yes, being ironclad is a big advantage, but it's only one of many innovations that happened in those 100 years, and most of those innovations were transferable.

Comment: @Nosajimiki - That is more a indication of the capabilities of Russia than anything else... The issue is that the F22 knows where the F15 is at all times *before the F15 knows where the F22 is* - the result is that the first indication that the F15 has there is a threat is that it is being engaged.

Answer (score 1):

**A stern chase in the Pacific.**

The timeframe you specify for the more modern ships was *right* in the transition between sail and steam. HMS Devastation did not carry a sailing rig, which means that she did rely exclusively on coal. And coaling stations were few at the time.

Added to that, the top speed of a sailing clipper under *optimal* conditions (wind, etc.) exceeds the top speed of HMS Devastation at full steam ahead. The sailing ship cannot count on optimal conditions all the time, but if they are near optimal long enough, you could argue that the speed almost matches.

After an epic ten-day chase across the Pacific, the coal of the turret ship would be exhausted. The chase does not have to last quite as long if the turret ship starts with less than full coal bunkers. Without power, the main guns of HMS Devastation are impossible to use effectively. The clipper would need to stay out of range of the 3-pounders and try to start a fire on the deck of the turret ship.

This cunning plan would be scuppered if the captain of the turret ship leaves the action to a [screw corvette or cruiser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Calypso_(1883)).

---

If you feel more inventive: Have the clipper rig a spar torpedo to her longboat. Try to catch the turret ship in an anchorage at night. But that would not be an action of the clipper as such, and impossible if the turret ship is moving.

Comment: The captain of a *Devastation* class turret ship won't allow himself to be chased for ten days downwind by what is essentially a pleasure yacht compared to his ship. Even assuming that he has strongly worded political orders to avoid engaging the impertinent boat, all he has to do is steer upwind and the puffed up so-called man'o'war will not be able to do anything except watch him go.

Comment: @AlexP, I was assuming that the turret ship chases the clipper, e,g. to prevent them from turning their guns on merchantmen,

Comment: @o.m. HMS Devastation - being an ironclad turret ship - was a ship meant by principle to act in line of battle. To have it perform the role of merchant escort is a waste of resources and a major warship. The role would likely be performed by ships better suited to the task, in the likes of HMS Shannon or HMS Inconstant. Armored cruisers like HMS Shannon would be built with sailing rigs well into 1890s for the specific reason of operating far from coal stations.

Comment: @JANXOL, see my second-to-last paragraph. I mentioned "a corvette or cruiser." The possible answer to this conundrum is the lack of radar and radio -- breaking the chase means the clipper gets away.